# Differential equation finding from general solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Could you please find the differential equation by using the following method:

Delete Arbitrary constant (C)
$$
Y = x^2+C_1e^x+C_2e^{−2x}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. You asked the same question at [Finding Differential Equation deleting arbitrary constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3563762/602049) just a couple of hours ago, with it being closed due to it needing "details or clarity". You should explain what the "delete arbitrary constant" method means, show what you've done so far, etc., instead of asking the same question again. Note your earlier question can then possibly be reopened. You can't see this yourself, but there's already one reopen vote pending there, with $4$ more being required to have that question be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes eliminate $C_1, C_2)$ by differentiating.
$$y=x^2+C_1 e^x+C_2 e^{-2x}$$ Multiply by $e^{-x}$
$$ye^{-x}=x^2e^{-x}+C_1+C_2 e^{-3x}$$
Differntiate w. r. $x$ to get 
$$(y'-y)e^{-x}=2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}-3C_2 e^{-3x}$$
Next nultiply by $e^{3x}$
$$(y'-y)e^{2x}=2xe^{2x}-x^2e^{2x}-3C_2$$
D. w.r.t. $x$
$$(y''-y')e^{2x}+2(y'-y)e^{2x}=2e^{2x}+4xe^{2x}-2xe^{2x}-4x^2e^{2x}$$
$$\implies (y''+y'-2y)=2+4x-2x+4x^2e^{2x}$$
$$\implies y''-y'-2y=2+2x+4x^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much Dr Zafar for the rigorous answer, it will help me to study.

Answer (score 1):

$$Y=x^2+C_1e^x+C_2e^{−2x}$$
You can conclude that $r=-2 $ and $r=1$
Where the characteristic polynomial is
$$(r-1)(r+2)=0 \implies r^2+r-2=0 $$
The homgeneous equation is:
$$y''+y'-2y=0$$
For the inhomogeneous equation, we have :
$$y_p''+y_p'-2y_p=f(x)$$
Where $y_p=x^2$
$$\implies f(x)=2+2x-2x^2$$
Therefore the equation is:
$$y''+y'-2y=2+2x-2x^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the Answer LostInSpace i need study more the root method.

Comment: @TestingTheSite you're welcome